Modeling time-varying variance of a signal
I have a signal whose variance varies in time 
It turns out, by observation, that these fluctuations of the variance arise when some other variables (let's call them input features) transition sharply from one value to another. I don't really know how to model this signal. I had in mind to model it as a Gaussian process (GP) where mean and variance would depend on the input variables but I don't really know what are the available tools in Python for such "GP's". I know there is the GPy package but I did not find any documentation where the variance/mean are in fact modeled as a function of other input variables.
Would you have some ideas ?
Thank you !

Given that you have a covariate which moves both the conditional mean and variance of your series, you could use heteroskedastic regression. Here is a link to the STATA documentation about this type of model (https://www.stata.com/manuals/rhetregress.pdf) - start on page 5 to see the model equations. Here's a link to Harvey (1976) which describes the ML estimator (https://doi.org/10.2307/1913974 - free to read if you make an account). He derives an iterative process for the ML estimation, and it looks like it converges pretty quickly. I'm not sure of a Python package though.
